# Loading data on Unidata Integrated Data Viewer (IDV) from a THREDDS catalog?

Tags: geospatial, data-visualization, netcdf, thredds

I am trying to load some data to IDV from a THREDDS server via the catalog, but I get error messages such as

> *Server does not support Content-Length*

I can add netcdf data from my local folders, but could not get this one to work. It seems like I am missing a basic step because I could not find the information that I am looking for on the user's manual either. I wonder if anybody had a similar issue... 
I am trying the catalog below.

> http://opendap.co-ops.nos.noaa.gov/thredds/catalog/NOAA/GBOFS/MODELS/201302/catalog.html

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That is the error you will get in IDV if you try to open a catalog using the `.html` extension instead of the `.xml` extension.

In IDV, you can open datasets several ways:

1. "Data=>Choose Data=>From a Catalog": specify the thredds catalog
   (using the xml extension) and then navigate to the dataset you want.
   I usually use a regular web browser (like Chrome) to locate the
   thredds catalog I'm interested in, then change the catalog URL from
   the .html extension to the .xml extension.
   For the Galveston Bay data, specify
   "http://opendap.co-ops.nos.noaa.gov/thredds/gbofs_catalog.xml".
   You will see a list of folders.  You need to click the dot to the left
   of the folder name to expand the folder so you can see the datasets.
   Then select a dataset name and click the "add source" button at the
   bottom of the page.
2. "Data=>Choose Data=>From a Web Server": specify the DAP URL of the
   dataset you want.
   I usually use a regular web browser (like Chrome) to navigate on the
   opendap server until I reach an OPeNDAP Dataset Access Form, like:
   http://opendap.co-ops.nos.noaa.gov/thredds/dodsC/NOAA/GBOFS/MODELS/201302/nos.gbofs.fields.forecast.20130205.t00z.nc.html
   and then I cut-and-paste the "Data URL" near the top of the form into
   the IDV URL box.
3. "Data=>Choose Data=>From the File System": specify a local NetCDF,
   Grib, HDF5, or NcML file.

Loading a local NcML file can be particularly handy when the dataset you are trying to load doesn't meet CF conventions, and you need to make some fixes so that the dataset can be read in IDV.